# shared library binding only to library not to process

Tags: c++

i have the following problem with shared librarys

create a shared libraray

```
class A
{
  static int callCount;
  A() { callCount++; }
}
int A:callCount = 0;
class Main
{
  Main()
  {
    A a1();
    A a2();
  }
}
```

now create an process which is loading this shared libraray more times and i would like have the callCount belongs only to the shared library not to the whole process

```
dlopen("shared.so", RTLD_LAZY);
// after some code i can construct Main() 
// and now i will open the shared object again
dlopen("shared.so", RTLD_LAZY);
// now if i construct Main from the new library i want to have a new 
// initialized callCount eq 0 but its 2
```

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The loading, and especially *reloading* semantics of run-time loaded libraries is very platform and implementation-specific. It is best not to rely on any sort of global state, and instead pass an explicit initialization function to your library. Maybe like so:

```
library_context_t context;

/* dlopen, dlsym, ... */

library_init(&context);

library_do_thing(&context);

// ...

library_destroy(&context);

// maybe unload, or reuse
```

Linux in particular does *not* reload a library that has already been loaded.